# The return value dosn't give me a number in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, binary-tree

This question is to find the sum of the longest path of a tree in recursion. Here is my code that I have come up with.

```
class TreeNode<T>(var key: T){
    var left: TreeNode<T>? = null
    var right: TreeNode<T>? = null
}

fun maxPathSum(root: TreeNode<Int>): Int{
    val leftChildPath = (root.left?.let { maxPathSum(it) } ?: Int.MIN_VALUE)
   val rightChildPath = (root.right?.let { maxPathSum(it) } ?: Int.MIN_VALUE )
    val maxChildPath = leftChildPath + rightChildPath

    return root.key + maxChildPath
} 

fun buildTree3(): TreeNode<Int>{
    val one = TreeNode(1)
    val two = TreeNode(2)
    val three = TreeNode(3)
    val four = TreeNode(4)
    val five = TreeNode(5)
    val eleven = TreeNode(11)

    five.left = eleven
    five.right = three
    eleven.right = four
    eleven.left = two
    three.right = one

    return five
}
```

The output I got was this.

```
-------Max Root to Leaf Path Sum-------
-2147483622
```

Not sure if it's the address of the node or not but he expected answer is 20. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If left or right child doesn't exists, then why are you setting to `Int.MIN_VALUE`, shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the longest path with the *maximum* sum? There are multiple longest paths in your tree.

Comment: `leftChildPath + rightChildPath` can readily overflow `Int` math.  What sum is expected for `Int.MIN_VALUE + Int.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: Yeah, The longest path with the maximum sum @Sweeper

Comment: I actually replaced `Int.MIN_VALUE`  to `0`, but got `26` instead of `20`. The reason I used `Int.MIN_VALUE` is because I had a similar problem that was solved similarly and it worked for me. I thought the same logic could be applied here, but It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your tree

```
      5
     / \
    11  3
   /  \  \
  2    4  1
```

Here's your `maxPathSum` for each, when you use *0* for the "no branch" value

```
      26
     /  \
    17   4
   /  \   \
  2    4   1
```

You're basically just *summing the value of every node*, that's why you get *26*. *20* is the maximum weight *of a single path to a leaf node* in your graph. It seems like that's what you're trying to find, the heaviest / most expensive path.

Look at your *11* node for example, where its branches are both leaf nodes - the max weight of both paths is just their actual values:

```
  11
 /  \
2    4
```

What's the most expensive path through *eleven*? What specific value should *eleven* be returning here, and why? How would you code that? (I'm getting you to think about it because this feels like **h**o**m**e**w**o**r**k)

---

And yeah, adding the largest negative number an `Int` can represent to itself is going to give you wild behaviour, it'll just wrap around to the largest positive as it overflows. Why would you want such a huge number anyway? What weight does a non-existent node have?

Using `Int.MIN_VALUE` *can* be useful as a way to define a value so extreme everything else will be higher than it, like a default value that will *never be used* because something else will immediately replace it as the "highest value".

But if there's a possibility you'll actually be returning that value, you probably want a better fallback that makes more sense as a default. In your case, since you're *adding* that value to your root's value, does negative 2 billion make sense in that situation? Or zero? You said in the comments that it "worked for you in a similar problem" - you have to know why it worked and why you were doing it though! Being able to think this stuff through is important